# Router.after is deprecated, is there a replacement global after hook?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to change the title of the page after any route has been rendered, to the name of that route. This is the code I was using before:

```
Router.after(function(){document.title = this.route.name;});
```

The [manual](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/) mentions using onAfterAction inside an individual route, but I'd like to do it globally?

Comment: Hi could you please read this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include as much relevant information and code with your questions, and it's likely to get good answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed this : http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#using-hooks

The correct syntax is straightforward :

```
Router.onAfterAction(function(){
  // your hook definition
});
```

Note : The guide is for iron:router@1.0.0-pre2 which must be added to your app explicitly like this :

```
meteor add iron:router@1.0.0-pre2
```

But the `Router.onAfterAction` works fine in `iron:router@0.9.X` too.

I suggest using `this.route.getName()` instead of `this.route.name`, see more about this issue here :

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/878

Comment: For some reason one of my routes doesn't have a function this.route.getName. So I've used this code instead now:
`Router.onAfterAction(function(){document.title = this.route.getName ? this.route.getName() : this.route.name;});` and it's working for all routes now. The route that is missing a getName() function is defined like this: `Router.route('foo',{waitOn: function(){Meteor.subscribe('bar');}});` the subscription is quite large, hundreds of rows of data and takes a few seconds to complete, so perhaps the delay in rendering the route is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The `router.after();` method although has been deprecated will still be allowed in the code in terms of syntax. As discussed in the IRC chat the best approach is to use the new syntax.

```
Router.onAfterAction(function(){
     document.title = this.route.name;
});
```

This should resolve what you are looking for.

Cheers !

Ryan